# ImageMagick scales down the processed images on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, minimagick

Here is a simple raw Rails model with single `url` attribute.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :url, presence: true

  def watermark
    remote_photo = MiniMagick::Image.open(url).write("#{Rails.public_path}/photos/photo-#{id}.jpg")
    photo = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.public_path}/photos/photo-#{id}.jpg")

    marked_photo = photo.composite(mark, 'jpg') do |c|
      c.gravity 'SouthEast'
      c.geometry '+15'
    end

    marked_photo.write(marked_path)
    File.delete("#{Rails.public_path}/photos/photo-#{id}.jpg")
  end

  def marked_path
    "#{Rails.public_path}/photos/photo-marked-#{id}.jpg"
  end

private

  def mark(mark = 'mark.jpg')
    @mark ||= MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.public_path}/#{mark}")
  end
end
```

The `#watermark` method puts a mark image to the bottom right of the photo and writes the file into `public/photos/photo-marked-#{id}.jpg`. It works perfectly on my local machine, however on Heroku the returned images that are ~600x800px become 10x15px.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in the way I've specified the geometry attribute value. In case of `c.geometry '+15'` ImageMagick takes the 15 as a width and resizes the image preserving the aspect ratio. In order to keep the original size and apply a horizontal offset the value should look like `'x+15'`, which is for `widthxheight+offset`.

All of the above is about the version 6.5.7 of ImageMagick, which is the one installed on Heroku. The initial `'+15'` works fine in the latest version.

Thanks to [@mschoening](https://twitter.com/mschoening), who helped me out with this.